# How to use Scroll on Elasticsearch aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 5.3. I am aggregating on some data but the results are far too much to return in a single query. I tried using `size = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` but even that has proved to be less. In ES search API, there is a method to [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-scrolling.html) through the search results. Is there a similar feature to use for the `org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationBuilders.terms` aggregator and how do I use it? Can the search scroll API be used for the aggregators?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In ES 5.3, you can [partition](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions) the terms buckets and retrieve one partition per request.

For instance, in the query below, you can request to partition your buckets into 10 partitions and only return the first partition. It will return ~10x less data than if you wanted to retrieve all buckets at once.

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "my_terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "my_field",
            "include": {
               "partition": 0,
               "num_partitions": 10
            },
            "size": 10000
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can then make the second request by increasing the partition to 1 and so on

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "my_terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "my_field",
            "include": {
               "partition": 1,           <--- increase this up until partition 9
               "num_partitions": 10
            },
            "size": 10000
         }
      }
   }
}
```

To add this in your Java code, you can do it like this:

```
TermsAggregationBuilder agg = AggregationBuilders.terms("my_terms");
agg.includeExclude(new IncludeExclude(0, 10));
```

Comment: How do I add the `partition` setting in the Java client?

Comment: Using this, if I have 20 partitions, will I have to run the query 20 times for each partition? How do I determine the size of the partition?

Comment: Yes, one query per partition. The first link I gave contains an empirical approach to correctly tune `size` and `num_partitions`.

Comment: What if I need more than a single field to be returned? This won't work in that case,right?

Comment: amazing how elasticsearch misses simple and straightforward SQL support :P

Comment: @brauliobo Elasticsearch has no vocation to be SQL compliant in any way, however, watch out for this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/xpack-sql.html

Comment: yep, SQL is much simpler, so they will eventually support it :)

Comment: @brauliobo you're comparing apples and oranges ;-) Each has its pros and cons... Where SQL fits, ES might no and vice versa, so there's no point trying to match ES and SQL 1:1. The only reason why ES provides an SQL interface is to make the onboarding of people with an SQL background easier.

Comment: @Val the 10 queries you suggest is just one in SQL and so much easier to be done! the querying language in elasticsearch is patetic

Comment: @brauliobo Then I'm wondering why you are using ES if the query language is pathetic... Why not a 100% SQL solution?

Comment: well, elasticsearch is the best in many other areas, but the query language is surely one of its weakest points

Comment: @brauliobo that's because you need to learn a bit more ;-) Sometimes if you need to do complicated queries, that's because you have not given enough thoughts to your data schema to begin with and try to do a 1:1 mapping between your SQL DB and ES (which is 99% of the time plain wrong)

Comment: come on, 10 queries with a long json instead of one simple SQL (without joins!) using a group by?

Comment: @brauliobo ES is NOT an RDBMS... and will officially never be one (no ACID blabla). It is a search and analytics engine. Hence my "apples and oranges" statement earlier.

Comment: @brauliobo You're missing the point, but we'll leave it there ;-)

Comment: @brauliobo if you think you have good ideas related to improving the query language, feel free to file an improvement on the Elastic github repo. Otherwise, feel free to ask specific questions on things you'd like to solve and people on SO will certainly help you.

Comment: What if I have 20000 buckets? In search I can retrieve 10000 max per request but what should I do for aggr? partitioning is not helping right?

Comment: @Val How would this work if you have a sort on the aggregation?

Comment: What is the ideal num_partitions respect to the size ? any formula etc ?

Comment: @AbhishekSengupta there's no formula per se, it always depends on the use case, but [this article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster) should get you going

Comment: @val : Suppose If I have 4 buckets or 4 aggregated values, then if I make into two num_partitions of size 2. After executing for each  partition(0,1) should get 2 bucket results. But it's not working as expected. Please share formula for caliculating num_partition.